# Rails nested attributes _destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, destroy

I have 3 models

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :offices
  has_many :contact

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :offices, :contact, allow_destroy: true
end


class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
end

class Office < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
end
```

I have a nested form which works fine, except for the delete. When I set _destroy to true for a nested record (office or contact), along with the nested record, the parent record(client) is also deleted.

Here is my controller:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
@client.update_attributes( update_params )
```

Here are the update_params passed to the update action:

```
{"name"=>"Anderson-Hahn", 
  "code"=>"87-0931663", 
  "projects_count"=>nil, 
  "user_id"=>"3", 
  "contacts_attributes"=>[
    {"id"=>"13", "first_name"=>"Brayan", "last_name"=>"Fritsch", "email"=>"lora@erdman.name", "w_phone"=>"(257) 752-2245 x261", "m_phone"=>"1-642-424-2725", "phone"=>"(762) 599-6951 x200", "linkedin"=>"sample-linkedin", "skype"=>"someskypeaccount", "position"=>"some position", "_destroy"=>false}, 
    {"id"=>"14", "first_name"=>"Leonardo", "last_name"=>"Auer", "email"=>"ricky@beerwalter.co", "w_phone"=>"1-254-525-3165 x3900", "m_phone"=>"501-206-2337", "phone"=>"1-913-256-5757 x3396", "linkedin"=>"sample-linkedin", "skype"=>"someskypeaccount", "position"=>"some position", "_destroy"=>false}
  ], 
  "offices_attributes"=>[
    {"id"=>"13", "country"=>"Syrian Arab Republic", "city"=>"West Ambrose", "address"=>"Vicky Via", "lat"=>"61.006562395442444", "lon"=>"61.681150392689545", "created_at"=>"2017-03-14T15:44:59.000Z", "_destroy"=>false},
    {"id"=>"14", "country"=>"Venezuela", "city"=>"Gerlachside", "address"=>"Herzog Mill", "lat"=>"-4.938697606908136", "lon"=>"7.983714813706257", "created_at"=>"2017-03-14T15:44:59.000Z", "_destroy"=>true}
  ]
}
```

I could not figure this out so far... Any ideas?

Comment: This doesnt look right to me, can you show an excerpt of the log from beginning to end of request?

Comment: My bad, probably I need some rest....
I had a dependent destroy in my Office model.